# Bootstrap Link Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link that goes to an other html file,but in that file the tabs links doesn't work, and I'm sure that the code is right:

```
<!--Criação de abas-->

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">

    <li class="active"><a href="#ocomite" role="tab" data-toggle="pill"> O Comitê </a></li>

    <li><a href="#simulacoes" role="tab" data-toggle="pill"> Simulações </a></li>

</ul>

<!--Conteúdo das abas-->
<div class="tab-content">

    <!--Aba O Comitê-->
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" role="tabpanel" id="ocomite">
        <h3>O Comitê</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
        </p>
    </div>

    <!--Aba Simulações -->
    <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="simulacoes">
        <h3>Smulações</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
        </p>
    </div>

</div><!--tab content-->
```

Here is the [print about what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuBer.png): the ID name appears in the link and the button doesn't work

Please help me cause I have to deliver this work to school.

Comment: You are not going to a different page. You are just jumping to a specific div on your page. You are still on the same page but at a different section of the page. You have to link to another html-file like `/ocomite.html` and create a `ocomite.html` file in your folder.

Comment: also note that "local anchors" won't appear to do anything if the page is already scrolled down (they are visible already)...

Comment: @rymdmaskin You did not understand it. There is an index file with a link to another file called primeiraguerraligadasnacoes.html, in that file the tabs links are not working, and the id name appears in the file path as can be seen in the print I made

Comment: @Deif For what I know "tab" or "pill"  work the same way